# Azure scheduler job authentication settings lost after a publish from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to publish some web jobs from Visual Studio 2015.
I'm using Microsoft Azure SDK 2.8.2.1.
On the Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com/), authentication is set correctly (Scheduler Job Collections > MyWebJobs > Settings > Scheduler Jobs > MyJob > Settings > Action settings):

[image]

After every publish succeeded (from Visual Studio), I lost my authentication settings on azure portal:

[image]

I tried to figure out how this can happen by taking a look at webjob-publish-settings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "MyWebJob",
  "startTime": "2015-02-01T05:00:00+00:00",
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Day",
  "interval": 1,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

But everything looks good.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search and documentation, the issue disappeared.
I supposed that was a trouble on Microsoft Azure. 
I think there made an upgrade. Wich one, I don't know... I would like to have an answer one day :).